# Pandas: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous using eq()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to check row by row the comparison of some columns values in my df:

```
df["ID OK"] = df.apply(lambda x: df["Buyer ID"].eq("0001") if df['Entity ID'].eq(df['entitysellerid']) else (df["Seller ID"].eq("0001") if df['Entity ID'].eq(df['entitybuyerid']) else "Unknown"))
```

Example:

```
Entity ID | entitysellerid | entitybuyerid | Seller ID | Buyer ID | ID OK
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1112      | 1112           | 1111          | 0002      | 0001     | True    ----> 1112 eq the entitysellerid; Buyer ID eq 0001 ---> ID OK = True
1113      | 1112           | 1113          | 0001      | 0002     | True    ----> 1113 eq the entitybuyerid; Seller ID eq 0001 ---> ID OK = True
1114      | 1112           | 1111          | 0002      | 0001     | Unknown ----> 1114 not eq to entitysellerid nor entitybuyerid ---> ID OK = Unknown
```

Got:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is the best way to do this especially when dealing with huge data ?

Comment: The output of `Series.eq(Series)` will be another, boolean, `Series`. You then supply that boolean series to the `if` statement. `if` doesn't take a series (or NumPy array, which has the same problem), and that's the error you get. So, if you want all values in the resulting Series to be True, use `df['Entity ID'].eq(df['entitysellerid']).all()`; if you're okay with just one value (or more) being True, just `.any()` instead of `.all()`.

Comment: You realise you have a quite horrendously nested conditional expression, making the whole expression rather unreadable. My advice is to split things up, so you (and others) can far easier understand what is going on.

Comment: You probably also don't want to use `.apply()`; there is likely a more direct Pandas-style way of doing this.